# UTF-8 input in Lynx

Tags: unicode, lynx

In the web browser Lynx I have managed to make non-ASCII character display correctly with the setting

```
CHARACTER_SET:UNICODE (UTF-8)
```

in `/etc/lynx-cur/lynx.cfg`. I also tried `ASSUME_CHARSET`, it makes no difference. Typing non-ASCII characters in input fields, however, does not work properly. For example, when I copy `狐` into the form field it displays correctly. Then when I press space, however, the insertion point is moved to the beginning of the line. If I do this with `Äpfel`, it also displays correctly when I paste it. Upon writing it, the Ä displays correctly but when I type in the remaining letters the insertion point is first moved to the far left and then no characters are displayed.

What setting do I need? My locale is all UTF-8. I use Lynx 2.8.9dev.1 on Debian 8.7. All other applications, Emacs included, work flawlessly with non-ASCII characters.

Comment: It works for me in Lynx 2.8.8rel.2, though I notice I'm using `ASSUME_CHARSET` rather than `CHARACTER_SET`.  Tested with Japanese keyboard entry to be sure the entered characters don't also appear in ISO-8859-1

Comment: Would it be possible to download / compile / otherwise test version 2.8.8rel.2, to make sure it wasn't a bug introduced in the newer version? If not, then I can build the version you are running (later) and see if I can reproduce the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57865/discussion-between-fox-and-august-karlstrom).

Comment: I can reproduce this bug on Debian jessie. Maybe you can use links or w3m as a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I have lynx version 2.8.9rel.1 (08 Jul 2018) on Manjaro 18. After installing lynx, I tested the page https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx and noticed that Chinese characters were not displayed correctly. Then I added the line

```
 CHARACTER_SET:utf-8
```

to the file `/etc/lynx.cfg`.

Note that the value is `utf-8`, as listed in the MIME name column in the cfg file, not `UNICODE (UTF-8)` from the "string for 'O'ptions Menu" column. After this, the Chinese characters on the above-mentioned page were displayed correctly. Searching for "Äpfel" or "狐", as suggested in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57865/discussion-between-fox-and-august-karlstrom) also worked fine.

I don't know if the bugs mentioned by Thomas Dickey are relevant; using the correct value in the cfg file is what solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's coincidental, a bug which was fixed [recently](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/CHANGES.html#v2.8.9dev.13):

```
2017-04-29 (2.8.9dev.13)
* amend fix for Debian #841155, adding check for special case where the
  expected number of cells is zero (report by Larry Hynes) -TD

2017-04-28 (2.8.9dev.12)
* correct logic in cell2char(), which gave up too early in determining the
  number of cells needed for a multibyte string in the editable text-fields
  (Debian #841155) -TD
```

[Debian #841155](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=841155) was reported last fall, but the problem was in the initial version of `cell2char`, added in [2.8.7dev.10](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/CHANGES.html#v2.8.7dev.10) mentioned here:

```
* rewrite LYRefreshEdit(), to display multibyte/multicolumn characters properly
  when using wide-character curses -TD
```

Briefly, Lynx uses curses to display characters, and to ensure that it knows the width of a multibyte character on the screen, it draws the text in a hidden window, counting cells.